# Move 2 DIVs (Login link & Shopping Cart) to last list item using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to figure this out for a mobile view. I want to move the account-navigation div and cart-navigation div to the last item in main-items below Customer Support. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="account-navigation" class="utility-navigation">          
    <ul>
        <li id="account-menu"><a href="account/" id="MyAccountLink">LOGIN TO MY ACCOUNT</a></li>                        
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="cart-navigation" class="utility-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/Cart" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"><span class="badge"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="main-navigation">
    <ul class="main-items">
        <li class="main-item"><a href="#">How to Qualify</a></li>
        <li class="main-item"><a href="#">Enroll</a></li>
        <li class="main-item"><a href="#">Customer SUpport</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery to move these elements? Are you trying to create a responsive version of your page?

Comment: You can't append a `div` to a `ul` but you could easily move the account and nav `li`s using jQuery's [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Answer (score 1):

You can move them with `appendTo` method:

```
$('#account-navigation, #cart-navigation').find('li').appendTo('.main-items');
```

Note however, that it will leave `#account-navigation ul` and `#cart-navigation ul` empty. Not sure if you want to remove them completely or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah I think I need to clone them so those divs aren't empty.

Comment: Then it will be `.find('li').clone().appendTo('.main-items');`

Answer (score 1):

You can't append a `div` to a `ul` but you could easily move the account and nav `li`s using jQuery's [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) as @dfsq suggests:

```
$('#account-navigation, #cart-navigation').find('li').appendTo('.main-items')
```

However, to my mind it would be better to have these items duplicated in the main menu but with a 'mobile-only' classname that you then show/hide in your media-queries:

```
<ul class="main-items">
    <li class="main-item"><a href="#">How to Qualify</a></li>
    <li class="main-item"><a href="#">Enroll</a></li>
    <li class="main-item"><a href="#">Customer SUpport</a></li>
    <li class="main-item mobile-only"><a href="account/">LOGIN TO MY ACCOUNT</a></li>                        
    <li class="main-item mobile-only"><a href="/Cart" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"><span class="badge"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.mobile-only {
    display: none;
}
/* Just guessing. Your media queries will be different */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-only {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Demo:

```css
.utility-navigation, .main-navigation {display:inline-block;}
.main-item {display:inline-block;}
ul {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
li {display:inline;}
li a {display:inline-block; background:#eee; padding:10px; text-align:center;}
li a:hover {background:#ccc;}
.mobile-only {display:none;}
@media (max-width:600px){
  .utility-navigation {display:none;}
  .main-navigation {display:block;}
  .main-item {display:block; margin-bottom:4px; padding:0;}  
  .main-item a {display:block;}
  .mobile-only {display:block;}
}
```

```html
<h3>Resize me</h3>
<div id="account-navigation" class="utility-navigation">          
    <ul>
        <li id="account-menu"><a href="account/" id="MyAccountLink">LOGIN TO MY ACCOUNT</a></li>                        
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="cart-navigation" class="utility-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/Cart" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"><span class="badge"></span>CART</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="main-navigation">
    <ul class="main-items">
        <li class="main-item"><a href="#">How to Qualify</a></li>
        <li class="main-item"><a href="#">Enroll</a></li>
        <li class="main-item"><a href="#">Customer SUpport</a></li>
        <li class="main-item mobile-only"><a href="account/">LOGIN TO MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
        <li class="main-item mobile-only"><a href="/Cart" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"><span class="badge"></span>CART</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```